# As a telegram bot, what is the best way to authenticate the owner of a telegram channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a way for a telegram bot to know who is the administrator of a channel?

One way to do this is to send a verification code to channel admin and ask the admin to confirm the code. I couldnt find any API that allows sending a message to channel admin, though.

I can authenticate a user account just by asking user to send a message to my bot, but is there a way to have a channel sending a message to a bot?

Comment: To clarify more, I want to send notification about user actions to a channel defined by user. For this usecase user has to add my bot to his channel and then introduce channel name to my application so that I can send notifications to that channel.

Problem is I dont know how to ensure this user owns the channel and not wiring his notification to some other channel which is not own by him and happen to have my bot added as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is not required!

when you have `a1255412542_bot` and ask the user to add this bot as administrator, is it possible to a channel admin to add this bot as admin?!!

you can:

1. ask the channel name,
2. send a message to the channel to ensure that the bot is not the admin of the channel,
3. ask the user to add your bot as admin immediately! then press `ok` button on your bot,
4. then you send a text message (or `sendChatAction` for hidden test) to the channel and if successful, finished!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you are suggesting here. It seems to work but I think this is not robust enough and imposes a specific process to user (making sure bot is not admin first, then add and verify...)

Comment: ok. i understand. but there is no other way by current TG bot API.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of admins of any channel using this method:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatadministrators

Check the permissions of that user since it returns a json array of username of the admins and their permissions